# Recursive function to iterative, this function given g(n) = 2*g(n-1)+3*g(n-2)

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I need to write a iterative function for this recursive function.

```
int funcRec(int n){
    if(n>1) {
        return 2*funcRec(n - 1) + 3*funcRec(n - 2);
    }else{
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: If *you're* the one that needs to do it, *you* are the one who should make an attempt before asking for help with it.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I'd start with a piece of paper and a pencil

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this one

```
int funcIter(int n) {  
    int value0 = 0;
    int value1 = 1;
    int res = n;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        res = 2 * value1 + 3 * value0;
        value0 = value1;
        value1 = res;
    }

    return res;
}
```